# How do I snap my hair's scalp geometry to the main character in animation?

Tags: rigging, particles, hair

So I created a character and extracted some geometry from the head to groom his hair. If you may wonder why I even create separate geometry to groom my hair on, that's why when simulating hair it is better to have a smaller, lower poly mesh in terms of performance.

Now I want the hair to follow the character and deform accordingly during animation. I saw some people suggesting the shrinkwrap modifier but I don't see any shrinkwrap mode that snaps the vertices to their original sibling's position. All the shrinkwrap does is some sort of projecting to either surface or closest vertex of the original mesh. This is not precise enough. I need to copy the exact deformation from my character's mesh to the scalp mesh since I am also using shape keys to animate my character's face. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: You can add the same armature modifier to the scalp as controls the character, and assuming the scalp still has the appropriate weight painting it will follow the main mesh